# Dockerized Kibana externalizing logs

Tags: logging, docker, kibana

I have been trying to externalize kibana logs which is running in a docker container with no luck.  My docker compose is as follows:

```
  kibana:
  image: kibana:latest
  container_name: kib
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
  volumes:
    - /var/log:/var/log
```

And Kibana.yml - logging.dest=/var/log/kibana.log

However when I run it I am getting an error as follows in the container:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: EACCES, open '/var/log/kibana.log'
    at Error (native)
```

It looks like a permissions issue (I am running it on Ubuntu FYI).  I set the permissions on the folder on the host to 7777.  Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The kibana process is run as [kibana user (defined in the Dockerfile)](https://github.com/docker-library/kibana/blob/a747babc86c0235f94dc7b65d23743f4cbfd7bca/4.3/Dockerfile#L4) by the [`ENTRYPOINT "/docker-entrypoint.sh"` script](https://github.com/docker-library/kibana/blob/a747babc86c0235f94dc7b65d23743f4cbfd7bca/4.3/docker-entrypoint.sh#L10).

As seen in this [similar issue](https://github.com/kfatehi/docker-sinopia/issues/9)

> The dockerfile creates a user named sinopia and runs everything as that.
>   In general this is good practice, however, **when accessing the host file system docker uses the same uid on the host as is used on the container**.  Root in container has root access on host, and user sinopia with id 1000 in container is mapped to user 1000 on host.
>
> If you create a user on the host with id 1000 you can then grant this user permissions to the host directory as desired.

Check the id of the user sinatra created by the Dockerfile, and see if you can grant access to that same id on your host.

If you `chmod +777`, try again the `docker-compose up`. (that is done for other [docker images like `libreboard`](https://hub.docker.com/r/miurahr/libreboard/))

The [OP sharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5318004/sharman) explains [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804179/dockerized-kibana-externalizing-logs/34805064#comment57377136_34805064) why the chmod 777 wasn't effective:

> Yes I had the user created (so that I could run docker without sudo) and was UID 1000 GID 1000.
>   **However my volume mapping was incorrect** - I have mapped the volume to a non existent folder on kibana and config file was point to this one.

Comment: Victim of my own stupidity.  Yes I had the user created (so that I could run docker without sudo) and was UID 1000 GID 1000.  However my volume mapping was incorrect - I have mapped the volume to a non existent folder on kibana and config file was point to this one. Yes you brought a valid point up though and the error is too generic unfortunately.

Comment: @sharman Thenk you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.